# Gradle when to use system properties and when to use project properties?

Tags: gradle

What are the scenarios in Gradle when you would want to use a system property and what are the scenarios when you would want to use a project property?

Comment: Project properties is basically gradle internal concept and they should be used internally (I mean in gradle scripts, files, plugins, etc.). However when You need to *communicate* with *external* environment, then system properties or environment variables should be used.